# При запуске GULP выдало ошибку "SyntaxError: The requested module 'del' does not provide an export named 'default'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Использовал сборку GULP от Чертоги фрилансера 3.0.
месяц был в отпуске и не запускал, сегодня решил сверстать сайт, и при запуске GULP выдало ошибку. Не могу разобраться в чем проблема.

```
  file:///D:/from0to1/cfmoto/config/gulp-tasks/reset.js:1
import del from "del";
       ^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'del' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:121:21)
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\salam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-19T16_28_20_568Z-debug.log
```

PS на днях прилетело обновление на винду, может после нее что то сбилось?
потому что проекты открытые до обновления работают и gulp запускается нормально

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+requested+module+%27del%27

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переименовать импорт в:

```
import {deleteAsync as del} from "del";
```